# SSD потерял таблицу разделов

Tags: lvm, ssd

Месяц назад поставил на нетбук систему (на SSD), создав на нём сначала LVM, а затем 4 раздела: root, home, swap, crypt. Делал по-уму, с тримом и прочими задержками записи. Всё шло гладко до вчерашнего вечера.
Нетбук я практически не выключал, а погружал в сон. И вот вчера вместо пробуждения он выдал [это](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/301a6eaa2206/IMG_20141130_012512.jpg)

[image]

и не реагировал даже на Alt+Print+B. После перезапуска на SSD не оказалось таблицы разделов.
В попытках всё вернуть были задействованы testdik и gdisk. Оба увидели два раздела: root и home, но при восстановлении они не читаются (тут видимо надо сам LVM восстанавливать, но как?).

Кто виноват и что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Есть большая вероятность, что это ssd полетел. У них такое бывает (хотя в жизни я не встречался пока).